# Integrability of function against another function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

Let $f(x)$, $x \geq 0$, be a nonnegative, nonincreasing function with $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx < \infty $ and $g(x)$, $x \geq 0$, a nonnegative, nondecreasing function with $g(x) = O(x)$ as $x \to \infty$. I want to show that
$$ \int_0^\infty f(x)\,  dg(x) < \infty .$$
Any ideas?

Comment: @Szeto Thanks, could you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

This is always true.
To see this consider discrete version of the statement
where a[k] = f(k) and b[k] = g(k+1) - g(k).
We know that a[k] >= 0 and a[k+1] <= a[k] and the series a[1] + a[2] + ...  converges and  also that b[k] >= 0,  and the sum b[1] + [b[2] + ... b[k] <= C*k for some constant C. First note that since a[k] is monotonic and its sum is finite k*a[k] tends to zero (look at the tails from k/2 to k).

We want to prove that the series a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2] + ... converges.
To estimate the tail: a[n]*b[n] + a[n+1]*b[n+1] + ... a[m]*b[m] use "Abel summation formula"
where for brevity B[n] = b[1] + b[2] + ... + b[n] .
One gets:
a[n] * b[n] + ... + a[m]*b[m] = a[n]* (B[n] - B[n-1]) + a[n+1]*(B[n+1] - B[n]) + ... + a[m]* (B[m] - B[m-1])
= -a[n]*B[n-1] +  (a[n] - a[n+1])*B[n] + ... + (a[m] - a[m-1])*B[m] - a[m]* B[m-1]
First and the last term tend to zero  and the sum in between estimates by
(a[n]-a[n+1])* Cn + .... (a[m]-a[m-1])*Cm so by
C* ( (a[n] - a[n-1]) * n + ... + (a[m]- a[m-1])*m ).
Again use "Abel summation" formula; this time partially summing up  a[i] - a[i-1] terms to get that the last sum is of the order of
C*(a[n](n - (n-1)) + ... + a[m]*(m - (m-1))) so of the order of
a[n] + ... a[m].
And since the series a[1]+ a[2] + ... converges a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2] + ... converges as well.